# after 'use strict' looking for 'use stricter'

Tags: javascript, typescript

so I always 'use strict' in my JavaScript code, but I got bit by a silly error I made. While 'use strict' catches vars that have not been defined with either `const` or `let`, it doesn't do the same for object keys. So, I did the following:

```js
'use strict';

let foo = {
    update: ''
};

// and much later in the code
foo['udpate'] = 'This is what I have been working on lately';
```

Needless to say, after processing some 300K files, I had results that were way off, and no idea why.

So, what could have I done so JS would have warned me? Should I migrate to **TypeScript** now? Would TS have prevented such an error?

Comment: You can use eslint to config stricter rules.. and also typescript is written in a way that will prevent most errors.

Comment: I am curious, would TS have prevented this specific error?

Comment: Yes you should; I'll save you the koolaid firehose, but TypeScript has been great for our team for mitigating lots of bugs, including this specific class of bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Typescript would help here, though as Brad pointed out in the comments it's not the only way to solve the problem.

Typescript works through [*structural typing*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html). If you added types to `foo`, it would tell you that the `update` field is missing:

```js
let foo: UpdateHolder = {  // Fails because UpdateHolder is missing the property "update".
    udpate: 'This is what I have been working on lately'
};
```

If you don't add types to `foo`, it will fail when you try to assign `foo` to a method that expects an UpdateHolder:

```js
let foo = {  // Succeeds.
    udpate: 'This is what I have been working on lately'
};

processUpdate(foo);  // Fails because foo is not assignable to UpdateHolder;
                     // this is because it's missing the "update" property.

// This assumes that elsewhere processUpdate is defined as:
function processUpdate(updateHolder: UpdateHolder);
// or:
function processUpdate(updateHolder: {update: string});
```

However, because Javascript is a flexible language, Typescript would not verify for you that `foo` has no other properties. It would only check that the correct property is present, not necessarily that incorrect properties are absent.

Comment: maybe an eslint config would be the best way to prevent this problem?

Comment: I realized that my pseudocode was not exactly what I had done so I have corrected it. What I actually had was `foo['update']` but my typo led to autovivification of a key I did not want. Of course, I wasn't warned of that so I just thought the update was missing (as I said, 300K files later… dooof!)

Comment: @BradBall I've answered the Typescript part of the question and specifically left the eslint part out for other answerers; please feel free to add your own. I'm not so familiar with eslint, and I'm particularly unsure how you'd configure eslint for the presence or absence of specific keys without going with a full-on type system like Typescript or the JsDoc-based JsCompiler typing.

Comment: @punkish That might be a bit more difficult: Using array-style access like that typically means the object could contain anything without keeping careful track of its keys, which makes compile-time checks a little more fuzzy. (After all, you could have anything between the square brackets, including a variable!) I think Typescript can still help you out if the key is a constant or constant expression, but I'd recommend using dot syntax where possible.